# PHP equivalent to Python's struct format

Tags: php, python, struct, pack, unpack

I am trying to write Python code to PHP. But I couldn't PHP pack format equivalent to Python pack format

```
Python:

format = "!LLLLQ"
mystr = struct.unpack(format, str)
```

I am using like this

```
$mystr = unpack("!LLLLQ", $str); // But its not working
```

Because there is no ! or Q in PHP pack.

Is there anyway to achieve that?

Format codes for Python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Format codes for PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of what the functionality of the ! and Q is in Python (or at least a link to relevant documentation)? An example of how you want to use it would also be helpful. That way, someone who only knows PHP may be able to come up with some equivalent functionality.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Comment: When clarifying questions, please always edit the relevant detail into the question itself. And remember that the less work you leave for the reader, the more time they'll be willing to spend helping with your question.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following sequence:

```
!LLLL
```

represents 4 unsigned longs (32 bit) in big endian format. In PHP this would be:

```
NNNN
```

---

However, the `Q` at the end is problematic. It represents an unsigned long long (64 bit). PHP's pack function doesn't offer unsigned long longs ( Correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. There is no support for 'unsigned long long' in PHP

Comment: Yes, the documentation tells nothing about this. Can't really believe that. Let me investigate a little more...

Answer (score 0):

If you unpack the 8-byte unsigned long long using two 4-byte unsigned longs (`NN` format in PHP), then you can bit-shift the first long 32 bits and add that to the second long to recover the 8-byte unsigned long long. In Python,

```
In [49]: import struct

In [50]: c = 12345678912345678912

In [51]: struct.pack('!Q', c)    # this is the packed string
Out[51]: '\xabT\xa9\x8f\x81e$@'

# unpack the string using `NN` in PHP   
In [52]: a, b = struct.unpack('!LL', struct.pack('!Q', c))  

In [53]: a, b
Out[53]: (2874452367L, 2170889280L)
```

This bit-shifts the first number by 32-bits then adds it to the second number.

```
In [54]: (a<<32)+b
Out[54]: 12345678912345678912L
```

And this shows that the original number `c` is recovered:

```
In [55]: assert (a<<32)+b == c
```